# How to split window vertically in GNU Screen?

Tags: gnu-screen

I saw some body split their window to 2x2, I just want to know how to do that? I know the 'split' command in Screen can only split the window horizontally.

Comment: This is not possible in some (all?) versions of gnu screen, a custom patch was developed to do this and has been applied in many distributions. I believe this patch is supposed to have made it into upstream, but may not have been released yet. Consider using `tmux` instead.

Comment: @math - what do you expect on this Q&A? The A w/ 9 UV's is the right A.

Comment: Yes, I though I could promote it to accepted then. As the first with (currently 6) votes is outdated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

GNU Screen <4.01 may not support vertical split without a patch.
GNU Screen >4.01 supports vertical splitting.

The [Patch](http://fungi.yuggoth.org/vsp4s/) is licensed under GPLv2. Some people say that the vertical split in GNU `screen` makes the application slow but I haven't tested. I use [`tmux`](https://tmux.github.io/) (*terminal multiplexer*)

Comment: Note: This is no longer true. Vertical splits are part of the official source and Ubuntu packages ship with the functionality built in.

Comment: @JaredMcAteer, it may be part of the official packages Ubuntu ships with, but the newest release of screen available through the GNU screen project page is 4.00.03, released in 2006.  They may have the functionality in their git repo, but it's not part of a release yet as far as I've found.

Comment: I hate answers where it's suggested to use another software. +1 for [tag:tmux] nonetheless.

Comment: I think stack should take an accepted answer, once ANOTHER answer surpasses it in points, turn the accepted check-mark yellow, then add the green check-mark to the highest voted.  

This is totally based upon the simple fact, that the GREEN check-mark is supposed to the more realistic figure. However that is not the case.  The REALISTIC figure is the one with the HIGHEST VOTES, almost always.  

I.E. this green check is not the answer, see the highest voted..

Comment: Yay, another project that has moved off Sourceforge! edited link.

Comment: @BrianVandenberg the official sources are [in git](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git). The latest version there does support vertical splits.

Comment: This answer tells that screen supports vertical splitting as the OP asked and is *not even* telling how. This answer should be hidden due to too many downvotes.

Comment: @BrianThomas that is a great idea

Answer (score 168):

The latest version of **GNU screen** allows you split the window vertically without any external patches. Here is one way to get it and use it:

1. Checkout/clone/download the [source](http://savannah.gnu.org/git/?group=screen)
2. Build it in an easy sequence of `./autogen.sh`, `./configure`, `make` and `install`. I didn't have any problems with dependencies on Mountain Lion.
3. To get a vertical split use:

   ```
   C-a |     // Create a split
   C-a <Tab> // Move to the split
   C-a c     // Create a new window within the split
   ```

I don't think this is a reason to switch to tmux any more like others have been suggesting.

Comment: Is it possible to preconfigure screen to autostart with multiple splits ?

Comment: @Fedir Sorry about the late response. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Sure! You have to add `split`, `split -v` and `focus` commands in the screenrc file. Even you can place screen inside another screen to make complex configurations.

Comment: @Kellen: When you say "The latest version ..." which version do you mean?  I have Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06, but neither `C-a |` nor `split -v` work. For example, when I execute the `split -v` command the error message is `split: no arguments required`

Comment: @JohnPrior "From macports (Mac OS X): Screen version 4.02.01 (GNU) 28-Apr-14" has the ability to vertically split.  As does "From apt-get (Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS): Screen version 4.01.00devel (GNU) 2-May-06"

Comment: To unsplit a window  again, you can continue reading here: [Unix: How to unsplit in screen](http://superuser.com/q/243459/63279)

Comment: @DaveAlbert, I installed Screen 4.06.02 via Brew on my Mac. Could not do a vertical split still. :(

Answer (score 47):

Check out the video tutorial on [Split Screen with Screen in Linux - BASH](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dFdqyccdWUE) . At time 2:00 minute, there would be a solution.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>   # Create another window

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd> # Moving from another window

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd>   # Create new session

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>|</kbd>   # Splitting vertical (pipe symbol)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>   # Splitting horizontal

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>   # Close a window

Comment: Note that to close a region it's capital `X` meaning `ctrl-a shift-x`. If we do `ctrl-a x` (small x) it actually causes the screen to lock.

Answer (score 9):

Use the `-v` option to `split` command in `screen`.  From the manpage:

```
   Split  the current region into two new ones. All regions on the display
   are resized to make room for the new region. The blank window  is  dis‐
   played  on  the  new  region. Splits are made horizontally unless -v is
   used. Use the "remove" or the "only" command  to  delete  regions.  Use
   "focus" to toggle between regions.
```

Comment: Which `split` command are you referring to?

Comment: As mentioned, the command _in_ `screen`.

Comment: it does not accept arguments. :(

Comment: google says we need a patch for vertical split.

Comment: It works here (Ubuntu 11.10), also with shortcur `C-a |`.

Comment: So, in order to input commands in screen, one needs to do `C-a :` (control a, colon). There you can do `split` or `split -v`. `C-a |` is a shortcut for a vertical split, though.

Answer (score 2):

### A WITHOUT using bind-key open way

Since I google out many of videos are telling us to use bind-keys, I tidy up some steps that we can open GNU screen by code...

1. save the following context to [`~/.screenrc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Startup-Files) or `/etc/screenrc` or any text file

> ```
> screen 1 top
> split -v
> focus right
> screen 2 python3 -m http.server 0
> split -v
> focus right
> screen 3 nano .bashrc
> ```

**Note**: change the command `top`, `python3 -m http.server 0`, `nano .bashrc` as you want

2. run the following command

> ```
> screen
> ```

or

> ```
> screen -c ~/.screenrc
> ```

**Note**: If your file **DID NOT** save to `~/.screenrc` or `/etc/screenrc` , the first command would become **NOT WORKING**.

3. enjoy your split windows

**Note**: If the command **terminated**, the split window will become blank. To solve this problem, you can run `exec echo "hello world"` instead.

4. close GNU-screen by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>\</kbd>

---

Reference:

- [Screen User’s Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html)
- [using screen to split the terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442646/using-screen-to-split-the-terminal)

---

### Vertically way

> ```
> screen 1 top
> split
> focus down
> screen 2 python3 -m http.server 0
> split
> focus down
> screen 3 nano .bashrc
> ```