# using screen to split the terminal

Tags: gnu-screen

In a `bash` script I want to show the user a file with `less`, but I don't want `less` to take up the whole terminal: I need to keep some informations visible in the terminal while the user browses the file with `less`.

I googled for `terminal split linux` and all the results refer to the `screen` command.

After several hours of trials end errors I believe I've come up with a mostly working solution. I've created a `screen.rc` file containing:

```
split
screen 1 less /etc/passwd
focus down
resize 10
screen 2
exec !.. echo Informations area
focus up
```

Now, in my `bash` script, I can run

```
screen -c screen.rc
```

and it creates a split terminal with `less /etc/passwd` output in the top region and `Information area` in the bottom one and the top region is receiving user input, which is exactly the intended behavior. Almost perfect, except when the user hits `q` to terminate `less`, `screen` does not terminate, because there's still a running shell in the bottom region. The user now needs to focus the bottom region (CTRL+a TAB) and hit Ctrl+d to terminate the running `bash`.

So the sequence to exit my custom `less` file viewer has now become `q` `CTRL+a` `TAB` `CTRL+d`: quite a lot of keystrokes only to exit a text file viewer...

How can I make `screen` terminate immediately when the top region `less` command quits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending the `quit` command will tell screen to quit, so replace the `less` command with:

```
screen 1 sh -c 'less /etc/passwd ; screen -S "${STY}" -X quit'
```

or something to that effect.

Comment: can you please explain that `"${STY}"`? Thanks.

Comment: [STY – Alternate socket name.](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen)