# Why screen is not splitting my GNOME terminal?

Tags: shell, terminal, command, split, terminal-multiplexer

I am working in a remote `Linux` box using `VNC`.I have a single  terminal with lots of tabs opened in my system. How can I split them using the `screen` utility? Does the `screen` utility work with already opened tabs or do I need to close all existing tabs to try it out ?

I have been [through this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7455/28032) but it is not working for me.I tried to open a new terminal using <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> then <kbd>c</kbd> but it just doesn't do anything . I am using `Red Hat Linux` and `GNOME terminal 1.16.0`.

I can see `screen` is there in my system as shown below:

```
 [subhrcho@slc04lyo pcbpel]$ which screen
 /usr/bin/screen
```

But I can't find `tmux`.

```
[subhrcho@slc04lyo pcbpel]$ which tmux
tmux: Command not found.
```

Here's the linux version :

```
[subhrcho@slc04lyo pcbpel]$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.8 (Tikanga)
```

**Edit1**: Even if I close all the tabs and open a single window as suggested by @Jander, and then type <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> then <kbd>c</kbd> I am seeing the character `c` is just getting printed in the shell. Am I missing something obvious ?

**Edit2**: Turns out that I never actually ran `screen` command (Thanks to @andcoz). Now I can see my terminal getting split into horizontal sections but not vertically .

Comment: @Macro it was a typo. I tried with screen .see the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read carefully your question and I have a simple obvious suspect: did you run `screen`?

Inside your "gnome-terminal", you have to run the `screen` program. After you'll start the program inside the terminal, you'd use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> sequence to split your terminal.

Answer (score 3):

Programs like `screen` (and `tmux`) are conceptually similar to, but completely separate from, Gnome-Terminal's idea of tabs.  `screen` runs inside a terminal window (or a single Gnome-Terminal tab) and creates its own "sub-windows".  So you can use `screen` to show two "`screen` windows" side by side, but you can't use it to do the same with your Gnome Terminal tabs.

Likewise, `screen` doesn't know anything about `tmux`, or vice versa... and for that matter, if we want to jump from terminals to web browsers, Firefox doesn't know about Konqueror's tabs, or Epiphany's.  It's the same principle.

If you want to put two Gnome-Terminal tabs side by side, you could go to the Tabs menu and choose "Detach Tab", then move the resulting window.

Comment: I closed all existing tabs. Then started a new window (not a tab). Then typed `ctrl+a` then `c`. It does nothing and the character `c` is printed in the shell.

Comment: That's because `gnome-terminal` and `screen` are two entirely different things. If you want to run `screen` you have to start it manually.