# How can I find out which version of screen I am using?

Tags: gnu-screen, version

Further to my [previous question on `screen` not splitting my terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/66446/28032) , I got to the point where I can split my terminal horizontally but not vertically . This [documentation](http://www.pixelbeat.org/lkdb/screen.html) says that vertical splitting requires `screen` >= 4.1. So how can I find out which version of `screen` I am using?

Comment: `screen -v`....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type `Ctrl-A` then `v`.  You'll get something on the status line that looks like

`screen 4.00.03jw4 (FAU) 2-May-06`

Answer (score 2):

From the command line

```
screen -v
```

From inside screen, type <kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>, where <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> is the default prefix key.

Note that unless you configured screen to not display its startup message (`startup_message off`) you'll see the version there as well.  You can display that message with the `license` command (<kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> to enter commands in screen).

Comment: "you'll see the version there as well" ..Where ?

Comment: "its startup message"?