# monitor command outputs in separate windows within a terminal

Tags: terminal-multiplexer, multitail

For a list of input text, I want to execute a repetitive command using each element from the list. In addition I also need to monitor the results of each of these commands in parallel. So I am looking for a solution to display the repetitive commands output in separate windows in a single terminal console; probably need a form of terminal multiplexer?

So far I have the following:

```
for i in `command1 find msgs/Poly`; do echo command2 echo "$i" ; multitail -l 'command2 echo "$i"' ; done
```

which seems to open only one window at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [terminal multiplexer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_multiplexer) like [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) to split the screen into multiple panes, and then run `tail` in each pane. For Screen, refer to [the documentation for regions (i.e. split-screens)](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Regions). For Tmux, refer to [The Tao of Tmux section on splitting windows](https://tmuxp.git-pull.com/en/latest/about_tmux.html#splitting-windows-into-panes). Also refer to this post:

- [How to split the terminal into more than one "view"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/how-to-split-the-terminal-into-more-than-one-view)