# How do i make guake start with tmux?

Tags: terminal, tmux, i3, guake

i am using i3wm and guake. 
I always use tmux inside guake to have split functionality detach function etc is there a way to start guake by default tmux running ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set tmux on Guake Preferences (`guake-prefs`):
[image: Guake Preferences]

Or use friendly [Byobu](http://byobu.co/), which use tmux as default backend (change this with `byobu-select-backend`). Take a look at [my answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/355145/209677) if you prefer this way.

Answer (score 3):

Do you start guake automatically with your Desktop-session? Then yes write in $HOME/.config/autostart/guake.desktop by the Key Exec `Exec=guake -e tmux`
If not `cp /usr/share/applications/guake.desktop $HOME/.local/share/applications/guake.desktop` and make the change there.

Comment: i was starting it using i3 config file so guake -e tmux did the job :)

Answer (score 1):

Tmux as default shell interpreter for guake doesn't attach to any existing session and creates always new. I wanted it to attach to existing session to prevent multiplications of sessions since I use resurrect and continuum plugins.

I've put tmux attach to guake startup setting. I've left guake configured with default user-shell. So in case of crash of guake or something similar, I can just type tmux attach in default shell and continue where I left of.

```
guake -e 'tmux attach'
```

To force tmux to start new session if there is no current session I've placed next line into ~/.tmux.conf file

```
new-session
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it. In my `.bashrc`, I append to the end...

```
tmux attach || tmux; clear
```

That will start `tmux` detaching the last session or opening a new one and then clearing the screen.