# How to unsplit the screen in konsole?

Tags: kde, konsole

I accidentally clicked some shortcuts, and now my konsole screen is split.

I don't want it, how can I unsplit it?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/how-to-split-the-terminal-into-more-than-one-view

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely you accidentally hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>(</kbd> (split view left/right) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>)</kbd> (split view top/bottom).

To revert that, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> (default shortcut) to close them one by one.

More information is in the [Konsole Command Reference](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/konsole/konsole/commandreference.html#view-menu).

Comment: Are you sure? The goal is not to close a terminal, but to stop the split.

Comment: @user259412 Yes, I am sure. Neither of those commands will close the terminal, but they will close the views that make up the split. What version of Konsole are you using?

Answer (score 1):

In the menu "View", choose option "Split View", there "Close active view". It closes a split part inside the Konsole. Do it until you have only one.

If there is no menubar on the top of the Konsole window, then you can enable it in the popup menu by a right click (option "show menu list"). After it is visible, you can make it disappeared again in the "Settings" option.

<sub>The actual menu/option names were translated back to English, thus they may unexact. Anybody using an English KDE, feel free to fix it.</sub>